# Why Kubernetes Ingress modifies my JWT token in the browser

Tags: asp.net, cookies, jwt, kubernetes-ingress

I am using ingress nginx as my API gateway

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: ingress-srv
    annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "http://localhost:4200"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: PostIt
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-path: "/"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "900"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "900"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-samesite: None
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-conditional-samesite-none: "true"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-secure: "true"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: persistent
spec:
    tls:
        - hosts:
              - acme.com
          secretName: tlssecret
    rules:
        - host: acme.com
          http:
              paths:
                  - path: /api/users
                    pathType: Prefix
                    backend:
                        service:
                            name: postit-users-clusterip-srv
                            port:
                                number: 80
                  - path: /api/account
                    pathType: Prefix
                    backend:
                        service:
                            name: postit-users-clusterip-srv
                            port:
                                number: 80
                  - path: /api/posts
                    pathType: Prefix
                    backend:
                        service:
                            name: postit-posts-clusterip-srv
                            port:
                                number: 80
                  - path: /api/comments
                    pathType: Prefix
                    backend:
                        service:
                            name: postit-posts-clusterip-srv
                            port:
                                number: 80
                  - path: /api/likes
                    pathType: Prefix
                    backend:
                        service:
                            name: postit-posts-clusterip-srv
                            port:
                                number: 80
```

whenever my JWT cookie passes it changes the value

```
PostIt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.2heVCyj5_Stx5IMuZ-nobDlaF6QsVF87uPgSRinxCw0; max-age=900; path=/; secure; httponly
```

it changes to

```
PostIt=1695463205.424.2056.249407|3d359a44c8bbe4174da37a1ce29bef0e; Expires=Sat, 23-Sep-23 10:15:04 GMT; Max-Age=900; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
```

and when i read the cookie on the .net backend service request i get

```
[{"Key": "PostIt", "Value": "1695462454.676.2159.490155|3d359a44c8bbe4174da37a1ce29bef0e", "$type": "KeyValuePair`2"}]
```

I have tried adding these annotations expecting that it would prevent it from changing or at least somehow turn back when i read it on the .net backend service but nothing changes.

```
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: PostIt
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-path: "/"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "900"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "900"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-samesite: None
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-conditional-samesite-none: "true"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-secure: "true"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: persistent
```

I have tried doing it in Postman and the JWT cookie works and does not change.